# VSCode Integrated Terminal not loading Django

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code

Anaconda:1.8.3
VScode:  1.22.2
Mac:     10.13.4

Just upgraded to Anaconda 1.8.3 and now cannot access Django packages.

from the conda python environment prompt I get:

```
Last login: Sun Apr 29 19:21:31 on ttys001
/Users/bill/.anaconda/navigator/a.tool ; exit;
Bills-iMac:~ bill$ /Users/bill/.anaconda/navigator/a.tool ; exit;
Python 3.6.4 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jan 16 2018, 12:04:33) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import django
>>> django.VERSION
(2, 0, 2, 'final', 0)
>>>
```

So I know that Django is installed and can be imported from the terminal.  From within the VSCode integrated terminal I get:

```
Bills-iMac:Prov bill$ python manage.py makemigrations
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 14, in <module>
    ) from exc
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
Bills-iMac:Prov bill$
```

Within the VSCode Settings my `python.pythonPath` hasn't changed - it is still:

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "/anaconda3/envs/py36"
}
```

Within the `venv` the path is:

```
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.path)
['', '/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python36.zip', '/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6', '/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
>>>
```

I've updating the settings in VScode to the `sys.path` above - but that didn't change anything.  I know that the package is installed and I know I can get to in from the prompt, but I can't get VScode to work.  If it is a `path` issue, I'm not sure how to fix it - I'm guessing it is something more - just not sure what.

## Update

I just realized that if I change the `pythonPath` in VScode settings that the `pylint` in VScode throws an error - it can not find the Django packages.  That tells me that somehow the VScode has the right settings to resolve the paths - but is still unable to import the packages when the program is run from the `integrated terminal`.  I can also run `python manage.py` for `makemigrations`, `migrate` and `runserver` from the `venv` terminal (outside of VScode) - now I'm less sure as to what the problem is but it seems to be specific to the VScode `integrated terminal`.

Comment: [Anaconda 5](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/release-notes#anaconda-5-1-0-feb-15-2018) is latest, why are you using Anaconda 1.8 which was released in 2013? and your python path should be in environment variables

Comment: @Prateek - when I look at the "About Anaconda Navigator" it shows version 1.8.3, but it is the latest version which includes the VScode Launcher on the Home page (?).  It is odd - not sure why - when updating anaconda-navigator it returns up to date.  With regard to the environment variables, from the `Command Palette`, `Python: Select Interpreter` - it is referencing `/Anaconda3/envs/py36/bin/python` which I believe is correct.  Is there another place to store the environment variable for the interpreter?

Comment: [Anaconda Navigator v1.8.3](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/navigator/release-notes) vs. [Anaconda Distribution v.5.1.0](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/release-notes).  My reference was to Anaconda Navigator...

Comment: thats what I thought , you would be referring some client software not the main one. I do not have Anaconda but I access Python with VS too. By environment variable I mean windows system environment , I hope Mac has something similar.

Comment: on my machine `"python.pythonPath": "python"` and `"python.envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env"` hope that helps

Comment: I have a laptop that I didn't update the Anaconda Navigator and both the `python.pythonPath` variables are the same (the laptop works; the desktop doesn't).  The `.evnFile` are both set at default...  odd.  I'll cross post at ContinuumIO and see.

Comment: Hope you have anaconda tools installed on VSCode.

Comment: @Prateek - I didn't think about a tools issue - thanks.  I double checked and Anaconda is installed on VScode - I'm at a loss.

Comment: What does your `sys.path` look like from your external terminal? I see that your prompt is different in the two situations and in your external terminal you ran some command called `/Users/bill/.anaconda/navigator/a.tool` which you didn't show in the integrated terminal. And your `pythonPath` isn't quite right as you specified a directory and not a Python executable. My guess is you activated your conda environment in your external terminal and you didn't choose your conda environment in the extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hit a similar program just now with Django on Windows and found this document: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/tutorial-django

As part of this, it recommends setting your Python Interpreter to your virtual environment:

1. View->Command Palette... or just Ctrl-Shift-P
2. Python: Select Interpreter
3. Choose the one corresponding to your virtual environment

That fixed my lookup errors as well as actions in the terminal, so perhaps something similar would work.

Comment: I revisited this and I think it was ultimately as you noted. Thanks.